# What does this sentence mean in the SETRANGE documentation?

Tags: redis

I am confused about a sentence in the Redis documentation about the [SETRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/setrange) command.

> When setting the last possible byte and the string value stored at key does not yet hold a string value, or holds a small string value, Redis needs to allocate all intermediate memory which can block the server for some time.

Does this mean: when Redis allocates memory for the last byte, Redis will check where the memory which is not busy can be allocated, so that the command will block for some time?

Answer (score 1):

Allocating large amounts of memory is slow. Since a Redis server is single-threaded, that means that this command could block the entire server for a while (potentially a long while) until the memory is available.

That kind of performance is unusual for a Redis command—and isn't something that can be captured by the time complexity (big-O notation)—so the documentation is giving you a warning of that.